# Realm - how to decide what to sync?

Tags: android, synchronization, realm

I'm approaching to realm to develop a simple shared grocery list android app.
First of all: is realm a good choise for my target app?

Furthermore I was wondering a really stupid thing. Realm allow to sync data across devices. My question, regarding my app is :

-I have 4 users. A and B share a grocery list 1; C and D share a grocery list 2. I don't want that list 2 is on A and B device for sure, and of course, list 1 should not be on C and D devices. 
How I could make it possible? Is there a way to sync only between two or more devices? 
Of course I don't need a code solution. Just to know if is possible to use realm for this purpose (and I'm pretty sure it's possible) and which mechanism/configuration I should use / read / look into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, a Realm file is fully synchronized, which means that if some data shouldn't be on the device, it needs to be in its own Realm file.

So in your example, each grocery list is in its own file (= SyncConfiguration).

We are working on a concept called "Partial Sync" however, where you only have one file and just synchronize what you specify.